# Stop flickering/repainting

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, repaint

So I have an java.applet.Applet that is embedded into a JFrame. The applet uses a java.awt.Canvas for drawing.
The code would be quite a lot for me to post and there is no "Small" examples but here is a picture at least:

[image]
Ok so in the above, the canvas is constantly being draw on by the applet. The JTextArea at the bottom is hidden when the toggle-button is pressed and shown when the toggle-button is not pressed.

However, every time I show/hide the TextArea, the Applet/Canvas flickers. The JFrame is resized everytime the TextArea is shown/hidden.

Now the small snippet I have for show/hide looks like:

```
public void setConsoleVisible(boolean Visible) {
    this.ScrollPane.setVisible(Visible); //Show/Hide the JTextArea.
    frame.pack(); //Pack the JFrame to resize it.
    frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() + 1); //resize the frame by 1px.
}
```

How can I stop it from flickering when it resizes and show/hide the JTextArea? My Canvas/Applet is already double buffered.

Comment: Sounds a little like you're mixing heavy and lightweight components.  AWT components are well known for flicker when performing custom painting because they are not double buffered

Comment: Hmm but I cannot use anything else other than the awt canvas and the applet (not JApplet). The reason is because this is what I am told to use and is given the applet. I load it from a Jar into the JFrame.

Any ideas what I can do? I was thinking that it is the resizing that flickers it.

Comment: Try using active painting instead. That would require a loop and tie up the main thread but the swing elements should be handled from the EDT anyway.

Comment: If you can't change the way the applet is painting, you may not be able to do anything...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 1):

The area you are painting on might be smaller than the visible area. So that some garbage get painted on causing flicker. Why do you resize frame only by one pixel? try removing,

```
frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() + 1);
```